# Create webhook url through API in Paddle payment

Tags: payment-gateway, paddle

I want to create a webhook endpoint in my paddle merchant account through API. Is there any way to do that? I could not any documentation about it. I know I can create it manually in the merchant account and I want to create it through an API call.
If there is any way then let me know.
Thank you.